# Python: How to create the folder in windows using 'os.mkdir()' with write permission?

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I am new to MS Windows Env. What I am trying here is to connect SFTP via SSH and download the files available in remote server to the local MS Windows in the created "Jars" directory.  With the following code, I am getting

> Permission denied: `<localPath>`

I tried with os.chmod() and stat. But, nothing works out. When I run the code I am getting "Permission Error" to the local path still.

```
import paramiko
import time

remotePath = "SFTP/SERVER/PATH"
os.mkdir("./Jars")
os.chdir("./Jars")
localPath = os.getcwd()

#SFTP Connect

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect(hostname=fromHost, port=fromPort, username=fromUsername, password=fromPassword)
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
sftp.get(remotePath, localPath) #Here, I am getting Permission Denied ERROR
```

The file should get downloaded from the SFTP to the "Jars" directory created in MS Windows environment.

Comment: Can you edit your code to be a [MCVE]?

Comment: Hi, Edited the code. Please check.

Comment: The local path is probably supposed to include the filename, in which case the error is from trying to open a directory as a regular file. The kernel returns a useful `STATUS_FILE_IS_A_DIRECTORY` error for this case, which would map nicely to Python's `IsADirectoryError` exception. Unfortunately the Windows API maps this status code to `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (5), so we get a misleading `PermissionError` exception instead.

Comment: So, can you please assist me with the solution? I tried appending the filename. But, files aren't getting downloaded into "Jars" directory. Instead, downloading to parent directory.

Comment: @furas Can you please help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using os.path.join() helped me resolve the 'Persmission Denied' Error.

```
import paramiko
import time

file = ["a.txt","b.txt"]
remotePath = "SFTP/SERVER/PATH"
os.mkdir("./Jars")
os.chdir("./Jars")
getCurrDir = os.getcwd()
localPath = os.path.join(getCurrDir, file)

#SFTP Connect

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect(hostname=fromHost, port=fromPort, username=fromUsername, password=fromPassword)
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
sftp.get(remotePath, localPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need permission to make certain files and folders. Try sudo.

If I need to make a folder with 'os', I always do:

```
import os
dirname = ".jars"
os.system("mkdir " + dirName)
```

Comment: `sudo`? On windows?

Comment: @Pancake_ thanks for the reply. the above code works in UNIX systems. But, in Windows env. I am getting the error "Permission Denied <localPath>".

Comment: Windows uses "\" instead of "/" to navigate folders.

try remotePath = "SFTP\SERVER\PATH"
and try sudo python script.py on your python script.